# Google Analytics won't track Events

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

**Edit: We are not using Google Tag Manager and this question isn't related to it - I want to know how you do this via code on the website and Google Analytics itself - i.e. without using Google Tag Manager at all.**

It's been a while since I used Google Analytics but am having a difficult time finding information which will help.

I have a website which includes the following tracking code on all pages of the website:

```
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-***********"></script>

    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', '***********');
    </script>
```

The *** represent the `UA-` account number.

When I login to the Google Analytics website (https://analytics.google.com/analytics/) data is being collected without any problem.

I want to add Events so that I can track some of the links. I added the following to one such `<a>` tag:

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'training', 'contact', 'Course name');"
```

I clicked on the link a few times and expected that when I went to *Behavior > Events > Overview* in Analytics it would show an event had taken place. No data is appearing.

I've read the following resource, https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-tag-manager-vs-google-analytics/, to try and understand the difference between Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager; I noticed that the script on my website is being loaded from `www.googletagmanager.com`.

It says at the end of the above resource:

> Google Tag Manager does not replace Google Analytics.

So I assumed I can still do everything I need via the Google Analytics website.

When I try and execute the following in my browser console:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'training', 'contact', 'Course name');
```

I get an error saying `undefined`.

So I've read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274803/uncaught-referenceerror-ga-is-not-defined but this doesn't help.

I'm finding this quite tedious and wondered if someone can help. All I'm trying to do is track some events using Analytics, which I remember years back wasn't so difficult, but everything has changed.

Comment: GTM does not replace GA (the data is not collected by GTM, in particular), but I believe gtag() does replace ga(). That's not the most current way to use GTM, though - is it possible for you to change it? The current method would allow you to set up tracking without writing new functions in your JS files/script tags.

Comment: We use GA but not GTM - we don't actually have a GTM account as far as I can see. All I really want to do is be able to add code to my `<a>` tags that's equivalent of `ga('send', ... )` so that the data is picked up in GA. I'm a developer so I don't feel I have any need for GTM because I can update the tags within the code myself easily.

Comment: So - news to me, gtag has nothing to do with GTM. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events says you'll want `gtag('event', 'contact', {'event_category': 'training', 'event_label': 'course name'})`, if I'm guessing the meaning of the ga() inputs correctly. I have never used GA except through GTM, though. This page of the docs may be helpful too: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/migration

Comment: Found the anwer?

Comment: @Volatil3 No. `gtag()` is giving 'undefined' in the console. No data is appearing under Events in the GA website. We are not using Google Tag Manager and this question isn't related to it - I want to know how you do this via code on the website and Google Analytics itself.

Answer (score 1):

ga('send', 'event', 'training', 'contact', 'Course name');
is giving a reference error re ga is not defined (due to not using universal -analytics.js)

For global site tag (gtag.js) the following should work for an event

```
onclick="gtag('event', 'contact', {'event_category': 'training', 'event_label': 'Course name'});"
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events